# Python - Split String correctly

Tags: python, string, list

```py
string = 'ESO 12-4 356.0648792 -80.1770250'
```

I want it to be broken down into a list like this:

```py
list = ['ESO 12-4', '356.0648792', '-80.1770250']
```

However, the first part (`'ESO 12-4'`) can have multiple strings, so I thought to cut it off from the end.

**My Code:**

```py
print(string.split(' ')[-2:])
```

**Output:**

```py
['356.0648792', '-80.1770250']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you always have the string with the following format.

```
your_string = '<FIRST_PART(CAN CONTAIN SPACES)> <SECOND_PART(WITHOUT SPACES)> <THIRD_PART(WITHOUT SPACES)>'
```

If yes you could use [`rsplit(maxsplit=2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to get the desired output.

```
>>> string = 'ESO 12-4 356.0648792 -80.1770250'
>>> string.rsplit(maxsplit=2)
['ESO 12-4', '356.0648792', '-80.1770250']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the string and use the `maxsplit` argument of the [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. Obviously you should also reverse the result in the end. Try this:

```
>>> [s[::-1] for s in string[::-1].split(" ", 2)[::-1]]
['ESO 12-4', '356.0648792', '-80.1770250']
```

Edit: You should probably use the `.rsplit()` method as @AbdulNiyasPM posted instead of using this convoluted method.

Answer (score 0):

Im new in python, i love `@Abdul Niyas P M` `@Selcuk` answers.

```
string = 'ESO 12-4 356.0648792 -80.1770250'
l = len(string.split())
print(string.rsplit(maxsplit=l-2))

#['ESO 12-4', '356.0648792', '-80.1770250']
```

Comment: This is not what OP expects. It will split incorrectly when there are more than 2 parts in the beginning (i.e. it will fail for `"FOO BAR BAZ 356.06 -80.17"`).

Answer (score -1):

You can use regexp to extract the "12-4" and use it to split the string

```
>>>import re
>>>string = 'ESO 12-4 356.0648792 -80.1770250'
>>>matched_string = re.findall(r'[0-9]+-[0-9]+', string)[0]
>>>[string.split(matched_string)[0] + ' ' + matched_string, string.split(' ')[-2] , string.split(' ')[-1]])
['ESO  12-4', '356.0648792', '-80.1770250']
```

Comment: Note that it introduces an extra space: `'ESO  12-4'`.